# Android READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission working correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making an app that loads in OBJ and MTL files and then shows it on screen for the user to rotate. I'm testing this on a phone running Android 6.0.1. 
The OBJ and MTL files are located in a directory called 'models' on the phone. To choose a file in the app, i need to open a menu and click '**Open**'. but without the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, the app would crash. I added the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml and tested the app again. This time, i could click on '**Open**' and see the listview where all the files should be, except i could not see any files. The app would also not crash when clicking on '**Open**'. The logcat is not showing any errors.

When looking for answers to my problem, i came across this:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
    }

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

    return;
}
```

Sniplet source: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check

Does it need to approve the permission for it to actually read the external storage and show the files in the app? Is this something i need to add to my code? 
I can't seem to solve this simple looking 'error', even after looking for answers.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="[REDACTED]"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="16150.8">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
              android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="23" />


    <application
        [REDACTED]
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `To choose a file in the app, i need to open a menu and click 'Open'. but without the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, the app would crash.`. If it is your app then tell us what you do if the user clicks on Open. How would we know? And apps dont have to crash if you catch exceptions/errors.

Comment: `Does it need to approve the permission for it to actually read the external storage a`. The user of your app is requested to grant the permission. So the user should click Yes. You see the dialog box coming?

Comment: We still do not see the code you execute when the user clicks on Open. So we do not know what happens. And under Android 6 and above you indeed need to add code to let the user grant the permissions you request in your manifest.

Comment: My god we dont have to see all onCreate() code. Only the code for Open. Please edit your post as i do not want to search for the Open code. Post only code relevant for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For api greater than 23 you need to add the run time permission.

1) Check the minimum sdk version should be greater than 15.

2) The maximum sdk version should be greater than 23 or 23.

3) You need to call the run time permission every time when you access the external storage or anything else.

4) Please refer this sites for runtime permission
http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/

https://www.sitepoint.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-m-and-n/

http://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-handling-runtime-permissions-example

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helped me with my problem quite well. If i had enough reputation i would upvote your answer. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1) Clear you data from `Settings-> App- > [you app name]`

2) Remove `android:maxSdkVersion` From the permission line.

3) Check the request permissions by code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { 
     checkPermissions(Utils.PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}else{/*open regulary*/}
```